# I'm trying to create a login page in Django with remember me functionality and session management

Tags: django, cookies, passwords, save

after the cookie used to save the password has expired the signin functionality stops working can someone help me figureout the problem. If the run the code without the the cookie having an expiry time it works properly but not with.... i have showed the views.py file

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from accounts.models import userData
from django.contrib import messages
from django.db import connection

# Create your views here.
def signUp(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('username') and request.POST.get('passwd'):
            saverecord = userData()
            saverecord.username = request.POST['username']
            saverecord.passwd = request.POST['passwd']
            saverecord.save()
            messages.success(request, 'User Created......!')
            return redirect('signIn')
    else:
        return render(request, 'SignUp.html')


def signIn(request):
    if request.COOKIES.get('cid'):
        return render(request, 'signIn.html', {'cookie1': request.COOKIES['cid'],'cookie2': request.COOKIES['cid2']})

    # if request.COOKIES.get('cid'):
    #     return render(request, 'signIn.html', {'cookie1': request.COOKIES['cid']})
    # if request.COOKIES.get('cid2'):
    #     return render(request, 'signIn.html', {'cookie2': request.COOKIES['cid2']})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if userData.objects.filter(username=request.POST.get('username'), passwd=request.POST.get('passwd')):

            request.session['uid'] = request.POST.get('username')
            # messages.success(request, "Login Successful...")

            if request.POST.get("chk"):
                response = HttpResponse("User Credentials")
                response.set_cookie('cid', request.POST['username'])
                response.set_cookie('cid2', request.POST['passwd'])
                # response.set_cookie('cid2', request.POST['passwd'], max_age=180)
                return response
            return redirect('index')

        else:
            messages.success(request, "Invalid User....")
            return render(request, 'SignIn.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'SignIn.html')



def index(request):
    if request.session.has_key('uid'):
        return render(request, 'index.html')
    else:
        return redirect('signIn')

def signOut(request):
    del request.session['uid']
    return render(request, 'signIn.html')
```